# angular directive to watch iScroll

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, iscroll

I'm trying to watch for when a user scrolls in an IScroll (v5).

I'm still quite new to angular, and just learning about writing directives. 
From other examples, I'm trying. 
My directive is

```
app.directive('watchScrolling', function(){ 
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
         elem.bind('scroll', function(e) {
            console.log('scrolling');
         });
      }
   };
});
```

and in my html

```
<div id="wrapper" class="watch-scrolling">
   <iv class="scroller"> </div>
</div>
```

I'm using ngIscroll to connect the scroller.

Is this the way I should be writing my directive? Or should I be using the $.watch method???
Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: You can't $watch an event, so `elem.bind` is a proper way to go. Do you have any concrete problems with your directive?

Comment: thanks @Stewie, my concrete problem is that it isn't returning any values when I scroll, so that's my starting point :) , sorry I can't be more exact. Not sure what I've got wrong.

Comment: I'm sure it's just a copying mistake, but just incase, you typed '<iv' instead of '<div'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `restrict`parameter. In your example the directive is restricted to element name, but you are actually using it as CSS class (`"watch-scrolling"`).

**Correct**:

```
app.directive('watchScrolling', function(){ 
   return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        console.log('Linked');
         elem.bind('scroll', function(e) {
            console.log('scrolling');
         });
      }
   };
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WwI6ROW4N0OEhfCo42M6?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks so much Stewie. Good to see I was on the right track. Some of the previous examples I saw had the directive name just hanging out in the tag, without being in a class or anything, and I thought that was really strange.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you want to create your own directive but there is a cool ready-to-use directive that works very well with both, IScroll 4 and 5.

https://github.com/ibspoof/ng-iScroll